# Write to file in Java App running on Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker

#### Background

I am trying to create a compiler web service, so a user could post code written in some language I made a compiler for, then it would compile, run, and return the printed results. My second iteration involves using Docker images to isolate the running of the code POST'ed into my running web server.

#### Problem

I am trying to write the posted code to a text file to run my compiler on it, but my compiler is failing on trying to create a file. My file paths should be correct, and my other test route is working. Here is some demo code that I'm trying to run, but fails:

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("/raw/compile-source.slacc"), "utf-8"))) {
            writer.write(req.body());
        }
```

In my Dockerfile that I'm using to start this, I have created the /raw directory, if it matters. I'm imagining that Docker doesn't want Java processes to create arbitrary files. Any thoughts? Below is my Dockerfile.

#### My Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src
RUN ["mvn", "package"]

CMD ["java", "-version"]

CMD ["mkdir", "/raw"]
CMD ["mkdir", "/classfiles"];
CMD ["mkdir", "/out"];
EXPOSE 4567
CMD ["mvn", "exec:java"]
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly? Also, have you tried different machines with Docker? Maybe a VM with a different Distribution. I have experienced a few weird bugs especially with Ubuntu and the `aufs` storage driver (with Java in particular).

Comment: I will add some more information on this tonight. It would fail on the open file, I believe, so I'm thinking something like a lack of permissions, but I will check and verify this tonight.

Comment: Have you tried running this code outside Docker?
I often find that, when debugging this sort of code in Java, it's helpful to log out things like getAbsolutePath() and getExists() on the path/file you're dealing with, to validate your belief that the path Java is seeing exists.

Comment: try to add following line:
CMD ["chmod", "a+w", "/raw"] after CMD ["mkdir", "/raw"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had CMD and RUN confused. I only need to have the final

```
mvn exec:java
```

in a CMD block, but the others needed to be runs. This is my final output. I also omitted getting scala. :)

```
FROM java:8

# Install Scala
ENV SCALA_HOME /usr/local/share/scala
ENV PATH $PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin

ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.8

RUN wget --quiet http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
tar -xf scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
rm scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz && \
mv scala-$SCALA_VERSION $SCALA_HOME

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src
RUN ["mvn", "package"]

RUN ["java", "-version"]

RUN ["mkdir", "/raw"]
RUN ["chmod", "a+w", "/raw"]
RUN ["mkdir", "/classfiles"];
RUN ["mkdir", "/out"];
EXPOSE 4567
CMD ["mvn", "exec:java"]
```

Thank you everyone for responding and helping me out.